# Starting adb logs on internal storage without going into the shell

Tags: android, shell, adb, logcat

I am trying to start internal logs within my android devices without having to go directly into the adb shell. I have to script this process so I can run it from a program.

I am aware that you can take the following steps to start internal logs on an android device:

1. Open a cmd prompt
2. enter 'adb shell'
3. enter 'logcat -v time -f /sdcard/LogFile.txt&'

The above will start a logcat process within the actual device. I can now unplug my phone from the computer and move around then come back and collect the logs once my test is complete. It's crucial that I am able to start this process and be able to unplug my device with the logs still running.

To my knowledge running 'adb shell' in front of any command would run as if it were in the shell. Therefore by this logic I tried running:

**Method 1:**

'adb shell logcat -v time -f /sdcard/LogFile.txt&'

This command did properly start the log on the device which is great. However, once I unplug from my computer the logcat process stops.

**Method 2:**

'adb shell "logcat -v time -f /sdcard/LogFile.txt&" '

This didn't seem to do anything at all on the phone and I don't know why.

**Method 3**

I have tried the scripting method as well where I run a Batch file that contains only:
'adb shell < Commands.txt'

Where commands has the single line:

'logcat -v time -f /sdcard/LogFile.txt&'

This doesn't appear to do anything. It appears to send the command once the window comes up but doesn't actually perform the action.

Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in application class. so when app will launch this code will start executing. and it will create new log file according to current time.

```
 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (collectLog == true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 6);
                StringBuilder log = null;
                Date now = new Date();
                String fileName = formatter.format(now);
                File file = new File(dir, fileName + "_logcat2.txt");
                try {

                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");//   d will dump logs
                    //Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");  c will clear logs
                    // process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + file);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                    log = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        log.append(line);
                        log.append("\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                try {
                    //to write logcat in text file
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut)
                    // Write the string to the file
                    osw.append(log.toString());
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});

t.start();
```

Comment: Is this written in C# or java?

Comment: Java (for android)

Comment: So I am not actually writing an android application I am writing a C# GUI where a user can collect logs and start internal logs on a device that is connected to the PC. This code unfortunately does not help me ...